# SDL2 + OpenGL crashing?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I followed a tutorial to set up SDL 2 with OpenGL, but when I ran the application, it immediately closed. I messed around with some values and found out that if I set the depth bits to 32, it works and stays open. Why would it support higher values but not lower values (like 16 and 24)? This is a problem, because I want my application to be able to run on other windows machines, but some only support 16 bit depth (I think?).

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
    return false;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3); //Useless?
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL with SDL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, resolution.SCREEN_WIDTH, resolution.SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

if (!mainWindow) {
    return false;
}

mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainWindow);

SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
```

Can I at least automatically set it to something that *is* supported at runtime?

## Edit

It also appears to work with 25-31.

## Edit 2

The main problem is that SDL is defaulting to GDI Generic (Even though my graphics card is updated to 3.1)

Comment: Does it work when you remove that line?

Comment: @Axalo No. I think its because it defaults to 16 bit

Comment: @name: What OpenGL implementation are you using? The behavior described seems very weird to me. Even if the implmentation only supports 32 bit depth buffer (which is very untypical to begin with), it shoukd still work when requesting only 16, as this is just a minimum.

Comment: @derhass I'm not sure what you mean, but I'm using libraries glew32.lib, opengl32.lib, SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib, and SDL2test.lib. I'm using the SDL opengl header and glew.h. And yes, it seems very strange to me too!

Comment: I mean the openGL implementation. On windows, you are either using the ICD which comes with the graphics driver, or you end up using microsofts fallback (but not for GL3.1). So what does `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` return?

Comment: @derhass It returns "GDI Generic". What does that mean?

Comment: That means that you ended up with Microsofts OpenGL **1.1** renderer, which is probably the only one to support a 32 bit default depth buffer at all.

Comment: @derhass That has never happened before. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: probably not requesting 32 bit depth buffer. Do you even have a GL 3.1 capable driver installed on your system?

Comment: @derhass Yes, I have used 3.1 many times before with glfw, and have looked at my graphics card information which shows 3.1. I have tried requesting 16 and 24 bit depth, but that causes the window to close instantly with no SDL error.

Comment: `SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 5` looks very strange if you are trying to get a hardware format. RGB 565 and 555 formats are normal, but alpha should generally be 0,1,2,4 or 8-bit, with 8 being the only thing you can reasonably expect modern hardware to support. Often you don't need destination alpha at all. I'd consider setting it to 0 if you want 15/16-bit color.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Either way, I still have a problem because its defaulting to gl 1.1. I don't get it; I've used opengl 3.1 before and know for a fact that my drivers are updated to that. This is beyond my knowledge why its not working :(

Comment: It'll only default to 1.1 on Windows if you try a combination of parameters that are not hardware accelerated (assuming you have an ICD driver installed). That will generally happen if you specify a really odd combination of parameters or simply request too many. The fewer parameters you set, the more likely you are to get hardware pixel format matches. 32-bit color and 24-bit depth buffer are the most widely supported hardware pixel formats, so I would try that out.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman But I've already tried removing all of them (except double buffer) which yields the same result. I've tried countless examples on the web, and they all do the same thing. I even tried updating my graphics driver (which is still opengl 3.1).

Comment: @name: When you used a 3.1 context in the past, did you actually call `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3)` and `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1)`? The extension that allows you to request a specific context version on Windows was not introduced until OpenGL 3.2 drivers started shipping, so SDL could be confused by that.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman No, but when I remove those statements, the same thing happens. When I used a 3.1 context in the past, I used glfw and another time, freeglut, and they both worked flawlessly.